# Installing AWS S3 R package

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to install the S3 package on R inorder to save csv output on regressions I am running. I tried to install the S3 package to link the Rstudio server to S3 but with no luck. This is the error I recieved when trying to install the `aws.s3` package:

```
> install.packages("aws.s3", repos = c("cloudyr" = "http://cloudyr.github.io/drat"))
Installing package into ‘/home/jessica/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  dependency ‘httr’ is not available
trying URL 'http://cloudyr.github.io/drat/src/contrib/aws.s3_0.3.20.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/gzip' length 47438 bytes (46 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 46 KB

ERROR: dependency ‘httr’ is not available for package ‘aws.s3’
* removing ‘/home/jessica/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/aws.s3’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘aws.s3’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpxNVUj5/downloaded_packages’
```

I then tried installing the `httr` depence package but with no success as well.

```
> install.packages("httr")
Installing package into ‘/home/jessica/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependency ‘openssl’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/openssl_1.3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1218896 bytes (1.2 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.2 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/httr_1.4.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 156356 bytes (152 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 152 KB

* installing *source* package ‘openssl’ ...
** package ‘openssl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Using PKG_CFLAGS=
------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
Configuration failed because openssl was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libssl-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
 * rpm: openssl-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
 * csw: libssl_dev (Solaris)
 * brew: openssl@1.1 (Mac OSX)
If openssl is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a openssl.pc file. If pkg-config
is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘openssl’
* removing ‘/home/jessica/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/openssl’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘openssl’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘openssl’ is not available for package ‘httr’
* removing ‘/home/jessica/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/httr’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘httr’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpxNVUj5/downloaded_packages’
```

Likewise when installing the `openssl` package. My EC2 instance type is a t2.medium.

Comment: You probabyl need `openssl-dev`. From the command line (not in R) install using your instance's package manager: e.g. `sudo yum install openssl-dev` for Fedora. In fact that is what the error is telling you right under **ANTICONF ERROR**

Comment: Read the readme doc: https://github.com/jeroen/openssl#readme: `sudo apt-get install -y libssl-dev` => this should do it for you

Comment: `sudo yum install openssl-dev` I tried that before did not work. Error no "openssl-dev" package is availiable. I also tried `sudo apt-get install -y libssl-dev` i got an error saying apt-get command was not found.

Comment: Possibly `sudo yum install libssl-devel`  ?

Comment: I am using an EC2 Linux server. It seems that in order to use the get-apt command I need an Ubuntu package?

Comment: Thank you guys. I was able to get the S3 package installed. I figured it out from the documentation Markus provided. Since I am using CentOS, the proper command was `sudo yum install openssl-devel`.

Comment: Though I still cannot figure it out. Which packages need to be installed on the Rstudio server and which are installed on the EC2 Linux instance. Here is the documentation of the openssl R package. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openssl/index.html . It does not mention "openssl-dev" dependency. Compare this to the XML2 package which mentions it in the system requirments: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xml2/index.html

Comment: `sudo yum install libxml2-devel` worked for me (extra `-el`)

Answer (score 3):

Here, both some OS and some R dependencies are needed before installing the aws.s3 package of `cloudyr`.

aws.s3 depends on three R packages: `curl`, `httr` and `xml`. These depend, in turn, on the `libssl`, `libxml2` and `libcurl4-openssl` OS libraries.

On a fresh new EC2 instance, assuming a Ubuntu box (but of course there are the equivalent yum packages for Fedora/CentOS/RedHat distros), OS dependences have to be installed for first:

```
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential libssl-dev libxml2-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

Then you can install the following R packages, in the specified order:

```
install.packages('curl')
install.packages('httr')
install.packages('xml2')
install.packages("aws.s3", repos = c("cloudyr" = "http://cloudyr.github.io/drat"))
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for sharing this answer. I worked for me.  I didn't specify the `repos` when installing `aws.s3`, but it seems to be working fine.